# Not able to pass API urls to the REST API app

Tags: django

I have my Django project split into three apps:

- frontend: You guessed it, the pure frontend.
- shared_stuff: This is where I've put my models, because I feel they might be shared between apps later on.
- rest_api: The, well, REST API.

All three apps are also registered in `settings.py`.

Now my problem is that the urls meant for `rest_api` app are also being serviced by the `frontend` app. Here's what my main `urls.py` looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^api/v1', include('rest_api.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please feel free to ask for more info!

Comment: You mean when you visit `/api/v1/xxxx/` the frontend app handles the request?

Comment: @hsfzxjy Yup. For example, `events` is an endpoint for both the front-end and the API. When I visit `/api/v1/events` I get served the HTML of the page at /events.  :|

Comment: Can you show 'rest_api.urls' please.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Yes, that turned out to be the problem. Please see my comment on the answer by user hsfzxjy. Should I delete this question? O.o

Comment: Yeah, it's usually the forward slash problem. I would add the slash in the root urls.py and remove it from routers register :) That way you'll have portable code.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov That's even better! Thank you.

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `url(r'^/api/v1', include('rest_api.urls'))`. Just add a front slash to the pattern.

When you visit `http://host/api/v1/xxx`, django will use `/api/v1/xxx` to match the patterns. But `^api/v1` fails the match because of the missing front slash.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Plus it makes Django emit a warning: `?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/api/v1' has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.`

Comment: I think I got it working. The problem was in my REST API urls. I had done `router.register(r'events', EventViewSet)` and changing it to `/events` seems to be working. Sorry for all the trouble! :-)